# Prism script is not running on user input InnerText

Tags: javascript, html

I can format text with Prism (see first code tag).
However I can't find a way for Prism to run on dynamic user input (second code tag).
Code is simplified, but there is more text transformation by the js function.
It seems only the stylesheet is loaded for the element with id=test.
Any clue how to solve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.23.0/themes/prism-coy.min.css">
   <body>
      <p>Write your variable below:</p>
      <pre><code class="language-powerquery"><div>let source=null in source</div></code></pre>
      <input type = "text" id = "myid" oninput="display()">
      <pre><code class="language-powerquery"><div id="test"></div></code></pre>
      <script>
         function display() {
            var p = document.getElementById("myid").value;
            document.getElementById("test").innerText =  "let source="+p+ " in source";
         }
      </script>
   </body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.23.0/prism.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.23.0/components/prism-powerquery.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1ocrxn57/